# Javac does not compile classes to target folder

Tags: maven, javac

**YES I did `mvn clean`.**

Tried in Maven 3.1.0, 3.0.4 and 3.0.3

My multi-module maven project's build (mvn install) fails at some module. The cause is that the last module was built with SUCCESS, but in fact the **jar is empty**. And then the next module can't find the classes that it needs to see.

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] myproject ......................................... SUCCESS [0.309s]
[INFO] myproject-service ................................. SUCCESS [0.011s]
[INFO] myproject-service-api ............................ SUCCESS [1.242s]
[INFO] myproject-service-spi ............................ FAILURE [1.422s]
[INFO] myproject-datap-lib-impl .................. SKIPPED
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19.746s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 24 17:30:57 EEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 62M/919M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project myproject-service-spi: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] C:\dev\mything\myproject\trunk-checkout2\service\spi\src\main\java\org\myself\service\spi\validation\fake\AbstractConfigurableFakeDetector.java:[12,55] error: package org.myself.service.validation.fake does not exist
```

Here is the complete debug output from running `mvn -X clean install -amd -Dmaven.test.skip=true > build.log` http://nopaste.info/7f07571993.html

In IntelliJ IDEA it all looks good, the class exists.

Not just the generated jar is empty, also the folder service/api/target/classes.

My pom file for service-api is very basic, just like the others that work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>myparent</artifactId>
        <groupId>my.parent</groupId>
        <version>myversion</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>myproject.service.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject-service-api</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        ... some local and external dependencies
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
    </properties>
</project>
```

No maven plugins here.

I don't think I have a cyclic dependency, because Maven 3 would detect this.

UPDATE

I've now got it down to this: a simple mvn compile on the module that creates the empty jar gives me this output in IntelliJ IDEA:

```
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myproject-service-api 4.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ myproject-service-api ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\myproject\trunk-checkout2\service\api\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ myproject-service-api ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 217 source files to C:\myproject\trunk-checkout2\service\api\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.908s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 24 21:56:49 EEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/232M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And right after running that, the folder C:\myproject\trunk-checkout2\service\api\target\classes is empty. So the 217 Java classes are detected, maven says it compiles them and puts them into my target folder, but it does not.

Update 2

I've compared the output of `mvn -X compile` of a module that works compared to this one (remember, all end in BUILD SUCCESS but this one has an empty target folder). There is a difference: the failing one lists all java files as "**Stale source detected**".

```
[DEBUG] Using compiler 'javac'.
[DEBUG] Source directories: [C:\myproject\trunk-checkout2\service\api\src\main\java]
[DEBUG] Classpath: [C:\myproject\trunk-checkout2\service\api\target\classes
... all the dependency jars
[DEBUG] Output directory: C:\myproject\trunk-checkout2\service\api\target\classes
[DEBUG] CompilerReuseStrategy: reuseCreated
[DEBUG] useIncrementalCompilation enabled
[DEBUG] Stale source detected: C:\dev\myproject\trunk-checkout2\service\api\src\main\java\my\Class.java
... listing all 217 classes
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[DEBUG] Classpath:
[DEBUG]  C:\myproject\trunk-checkout2\service\api\target\classes
... all the dependency jars
[DEBUG] Source roots:
[DEBUG]  C:\myproject\trunk-checkout2\service\api\src\main\java
[DEBUG] Command line options:
[DEBUG] -d (...) -g -nowarn -target 1.6 -source 1.6 -encoding UTF-8
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#beforeRebuildExecution
[INFO] Compiling 217 source files to C:\myproject\trunk-checkout2\service\api\target\classes
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#afterRebuildExecution
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.060s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 24 23:16:37 EEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/328M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've seen this bug report https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-205 and I do have package-info.java files in this module, but I've tried a pre-3 compiler plugin, same result. And I've tried with an annotation as described there, no luck either. So I don't think it's the same case.

I don't have a public static void main, thus this bug [Workaround for javac compilation order bug in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505857/workaround-for-javac-compilation-order-bug-in-maven) can't be it.

UPDATE 3

There's an abort in javac, without notice (-verbose turned on). Just 1 class works, all 217 fails. So I guess I have to try to find which causes it, etc... will post again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was due to a bug in javac. Some valid syntax it could not handle. That then generated the empty jar, and so on.

Comment: Can you post the problem syntax and your java version?

Answer (score 0):

First in your log output there are several hints about things like `${version}` which you should fix furthermore there are other warnings about duplicate definitions of dependencies etc.

I have taken a deeper look into the log output:

```
[ERROR] C:devmythingmyprojecttrunk-checkout2servicespisrcmainjavaorgmyselfservicespivalidationfakeAbstractConfigurableFakeDetector.java:[12,55] error: package org.myself.service.validation.fake does not exist
[ERROR] C:devmythingmyprojecttrunk-checkout2servicespisrcmainjavaorgmyselfservicespivalidationfakeAbstractConfigurableFakeDetector.java:[13,55] error: package org.myself.service.validation.fake does not exist
[ERROR] C:devmythingmyprojecttrunk-checkout2servicespisrcmainjavaorgmyselfservicespivalidationfakeAbstractConfigurableFakeDetector.java:[82,14] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  symbol:  class SimpleValidationResult
  location: class AbstractConfigurableFakeDetector
C:devmythingmyprojecttrunk-checkout2servicespisrcmainjavaorgmyselfservicespivalidationfakeAbstractConfigurableFakeDetector.java:[106,66] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  symbol:  class FakeType
  location: class AbstractConfigurableFakeDetector
C:devmythingmyprojecttrunk-checkout2servicespisrcmainjavaorgmyselfservicespivalidationfakeAbstractConfigurableFakeDetector.java:[97,8] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  symbol:  class SimpleValidationResult
  location: interface SomethingThatReturnsValidationResult
C:devmythingmyprojecttrunk-checkout2servicespisrcmainjavaorgmyselfservicespigenderresultAverageComputedGenderResultCollector.java:[4,46] error: package org.myself.service.gender does not exist
[ERROR] C:devmythingmyprojecttrunk-checkout2servicespisrcmainjavaorgmyselfservicespigenderresultAverageComputedGenderResultCollector.java:[5,46] error: package org.myself.service.gender does not exist
[ERROR] C:devmythingmyprojecttrunk-checkout2servicespisrcmainjavaorgmyselfservicespigenderresultAbstractAverageGenderCollector.java:[4,46] error: package org.myself.service.gender does not exist
[ERROR] C:devmythingmyprojecttrunk-checkout2servicespisrcmainjavaorgmyselfservicespigenderresultAverageComputedGenderResultCollector.java:[31,29] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  symbol:  class ComputedGenderResult
  location: class AverageComputedGenderResultCollector
```

which gives me the impression that you are using test classes or may be package names from the test area which will not work or you are missing a dependency to an other package.

Comment: those folder names like C:devmythingmyprojecttrunk-checkout2servicespis were mangled by nopaste (even though i selected 'plain'). they are not the problem. the reported problem with the missing packages/classes is exactly because they should be in the empty jar.